# Gmail URL Parameters

Tags: gmail

Does Google accept any URL parameters that will allow me to specify the subject and the send-to fields?

More specifically, I'd like to modify this link: `https://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=2&view=cm&fs=1&tf=1` to autofill those two fields with an email address and subject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out. Just add `to=` for recipient email address and `su=` for the subject:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=2&view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&to=EMAIL@ADDRESS.COM&su=SUBJECT
```